# Java synchronized ( ArrayList ) or Vector?

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

I know that `ArrayList` is not synchronized, but I can access it in a synchronized way as :

```
synchronized( arraylist )
{
   arraylist.add( "new item" );
}
```

or I can use a `vector` instead - which I see from every blog that it should be avoided.

Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: It depends on what you have to do. Start by explaining your goal, next we can comment which is best. Anyway, almost surely you're going to need more atomic operation than those offered by Vector.

Comment: I absolutely want the lists to be synchronized. Basically I don't want two threads to update my lists at a time. What is an atomic operation on the list?

Comment: @svasa if you only want to store elements in a concurrent collection, then a queue seems better than a list.

Comment: As an example - if I recall that right - you can't `check-and-store` an element in a Vector as an atomic operation, so although `check` and `store` are atomic, you don't have them together (e.g. you thread may be switched between the check and the store).

Answer (score 2):

There is a concurrent `List` implementation: [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) that supports concurrency and is better than the options described above.

Still, I would recommend using another collection like a concurrent `Queue` through [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and implemented by [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). I would ask you to provide more info on your problem to get more accurate help.

Comment: Is this Java SE 8 ? if it is I don't use Java SE 8 at least for now.

Comment: @svasa I use the latest javadoc available. Those classes/interfaces are since Java 5.

Comment: Ok. wouldn't CopyOnWriteArrayList occupy more memory?

Comment: Yes, but will fulfill your purpose. Otherwise, use another collection like queue as explained in my answer.

Comment: Can you tell me why BlockingQueue is superior to Collections.synchronizedList( ) if my need is a concurrent list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access a `List` and make it `synchronized` by using blocks as you have described. Note that you must also synchronize when reading from the list in order to be totally safe.

An alternative (and IMO better) approach is to use one of the following:

*Alternative 1: Collections.synchronizedList*:

```
List<SomeType> sList = Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);
sList.add(...); // synchronized, no synchronized-block needed
```

The returned list will be synchronized for updates but iterations must still be in a `synchronized` block:

```
// Iterating...
synchronized (sList) {
    for (SomeType s : sList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You can find the [JavaDocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-)

*Alternative 2: CopyOnWriteArrayList:*

You can find the [JavaDocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

> A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.

The second alternative is obviously more memory-consuming if you perform a lot of writes.

Comment: Why would I need to initiazlie my list using Collections.synchronizedList() if I am using the block synchronized( arraylist ) ?

Comment: You don't have to do that if you are using synchronized-blocks. But, you can skip the blocks (for writing) when using an instance of `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: ok, but if I use Collections.synchronizedList when iterating through them I should use synchronized block ? I can do the same, even without initiazling them with Collections.synchronizedList right?

Comment: I you use `Collections.synchronizedList` you only have to use `synchronized`-blocks when reading. You can do the same on a *normal* `List` if you put every access within `synchronzed` blocks (but the code will be verbose).

Comment: @wassgren You are mixing up reading and iterating. Normal reading operations as using contains() or get() don't have to be synchronized.

Comment: @flo, yes - iterating of course. Bad choice of words. Thx

Comment: should a call to size() on Collections.synchronizedList need to be synchronized ?

Comment: @svasa no need for that. Only when iterating.